# How do you show where on the board the user has pressed for a mobile sudoku game?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, sudoku

I am making a sudoku game in java - Intellij. I want to show the user where they have pressed and I do not know how to do so.
If you need the whole file its on the github:
https://github.com/SamirSydykov03/Sudoku-Varients-for-mobile-phones

Here is my Game.java

```
import com.example.sudokuvarients.normalsudoku9x9.SudokuGrid.GameGrid;
public class Game {
    private static Game instance;
    private GameGrid grid = null;
    private int selectedX = -1;
    private int selectedY = -1;
    private Game(){}
    public static Game getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Game();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void createGrid(Context context){
        int[][] Sudoku = SudokuGenerator.getInstance().generateGrid();
        Sudoku = SudokuGenerator.getInstance().removal(Sudoku);
        grid = new GameGrid(context);
        grid.setGrid(Sudoku);
    }

    public GameGrid getGrid(){
        return grid;
    }

    public void setSelectedPos(int x, int y){
        setSelectedItem();
        selectedX = x;
        selectedY = y;

    }
    public void setSelectedItem(){
        grid.getItem(-1,-1);
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){
        if(selectedY != -1 && selectedX != -1){
            grid.setItem(selectedX,selectedY,number);
        }
        grid.checkGame();
    }
```

Here is my BaseSudokoCell.java

```
package com.example.sudokuvarients.normalsudoku9x9.SudokuGrid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class BaseSudokuCell extends View {

    private boolean modify = true;
    private int value;
    private boolean selected;

    public BaseSudokuCell(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
    public void setNotModify(){
        modify = false;
    }
    public void setInitialValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setValue(int value){
        if(modify){
            this.value = value;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
    public boolean getSelect(){
        return selected;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return  value;
    }
}
```

Here is my SudokuCell.java - It does draw a tile, but it does not hide and it is drawn in all the cells. It does not do anything when clicked.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class SudokuCell extends BaseSudokuCell{

    private Paint mPaint;


    public SudokuCell(Context context){
        super(context);
        mPaint =new Paint();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawNumber(canvas);
        drawLines(canvas);
            drawRectangle(canvas);

    }

    private void drawLines(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight(), mPaint);
    }

    private void drawNumber(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        mPaint.setTextSize(60);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        mPaint.getTextBounds(String.valueOf(getValue()), 0, String.valueOf(getValue()).length(), bounds);
        if (getValue() != 0) {
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getValue()), (getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2, (getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2, mPaint);
        }

    }

    private void drawRectangle(Canvas canvas){
        Rect ourRect = new Rect();
        ourRect.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth()-5,canvas.getHeight()-5);
        Paint grey = new Paint();
        grey.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        grey.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(ourRect,grey);

    }



}
```